# Contact form placeholder text will not disappear on focus. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: wordpress, css, forms

I have placed the following CSS code to make the placeholder text 'disappear' on focus. It works for the first (4) fields of the form, however for the large message box it does not seem to be working!

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* Firefox 18- */
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* Firefox 19+ */
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* oldIE ;) */
```

The URL is http://dfb.a2c.myftpupload.com/products/garment-conveyor/ and the form is at the bottom of the page!

Any help or suggestions as to why the 'How can we help?' section of the form does not seem to be affected by the above code!

Thanks

-EDIT-

It seems to be working in Internet Explorer just not Google Chrome!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following please:

```
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* Firefox 18- */
textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* Firefox 19+ */
textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* oldIE ;) */
```

As the last form control is a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you - worked great! I just added *:focus:: to first line of your code so that the placeholder text was visible, unless clicked on.

```
textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* Firefox 18- */
textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* Firefox 19+ */
textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* oldIE ;) */
```

Comment: Ehm... are you the OP? Then you should try to log in as such, otherwise this site will think you are two persons.